# Remote Access Server for design software

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-access, remote, network-speed

I am thinking about setting up a server for multiple clients to log in to (2 at the same time max), so that people away from the office can use our (resource hogging/CPU intensive) design software over our VPN. My questions are as follows:

1. Is it even possible to get a good enough response time over the internet? (all internet connections are at 25mbps or faster, internally we run on gigabit)
2. Windows or mac?
3. What would a setup like this be commonly be called?
4. Any recommendations on hardware or setup considerations?

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing too scary here.  You could use either Microsoft's own RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) service on Windows Server 2008, or you could use Citrix XenApp (also on Server 2008).

1. At 25mbit or better, I'd have thought that remote desktop performance (Microsoft RDP) would be more than adequate.
2. Run the server with Windows Server 2008, clients are available for Windows, Mac and Linux.
3. Remote Desktop Server / Desktop Virtualization
4. Yeah, Lots of RAM in the server, and bundle everything together over a decent dial-in IPSEC VPN for security / access control.

Answer (score 0):

1) Assuming you use a lightweight protocol like RDP, sure.

2) How can we possibly answer that for you with the info given?

3) In a Microsoft environment, you would typically use Terminal Services for this.

4) see #2